# SQLite 3.8.3 or later is required

Tags: python-3.x, django

When I run `python3 manage.py runserver 10.0.1.150:000`

I get the error saying `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: SQLite 3.8.3 or later is required (found 3.7.17).`

so i go and check the version of SQlite by doing `LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/opt/atomicorp/atomic/root/usr/lib64/' python3`
then `import sqlite3`, and after that `sqlite3.sqlite_version`. I get `'3.8.5'`

I am extremely confused on why this isn't working and I have thought of some reasons why, like maybe the system isn't detecting the update or something like that.

[Here is a image of the error in bash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ojs4n.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually `SQLite` or `SQLite3` is not used in production and some hosting providers does not support it at all. I'll recommend you to go with `MySQL`.

References which might help

1. https://medium.com/@omaraamir19966/connect-django-with-mysql-database-f946d0f6f9e3
2. [Setting Django up to use MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19189813/14020019)
3. [No module named MySQLdb](https://stackoverflow.com/q/454854/14020019)