# MySQL.prefPane showing stop status

Tags: mysql

[image]

I have installed mysql using dmg from mysql website.
mysql-8.0.23-macos10.15-x86_64.pkg

package version: mysql-8.0.23-macos10.15-x86_64.dmg

I have connected to localhost server using: mysql connect -h127.0.0.1 -uroot

I am successfully connected and able to run operation/queries.

But not able to connect through django project. I suspect it is due to server not running. I am unable to understand when server is not running how i am able to connect from terminal.

UPDATE:

After reading [answer on dba exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/124974/mysqld-keeps-automatically-restarting) I realised it might be because I
ran kill  to stop mysql server.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting Django up to use MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189813/setting-django-up-to-use-mysql)

Comment: @AllanWind Thanks, I have already added connection details in config and it was working till today morning. Then for some reason I ran kill <PID> to stop mysql and after that I started facing this issue.

Comment: That's entirely a different problem.  Look at the mysql server log and see what it complains about.  That would be a question for the database administration forum not stackoverflow.