# I installed 'mysqlclient' with pipenv but python doesn't recegnize it and gives "Did you install mysqlclient" error

Tags: python, django

I installed mysqlclient inside my python virtual enviorment to connect to a mysql database.

But when I change the `settings.py` database engine settings from sqllite to mysql:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

I get this weird error telling me I havn't installed 'mysqlclient' package

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/reza/.local/share/virtualenvs/store-api-wAMLFNlP/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 15, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
  File "/home/reza/.local/share/virtualenvs/store-api-wAMLFNlP/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
ImportError: libmysqlclient.so.21: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/reza/.local/share/virtualenvs/store-api-wAMLFNlP/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/reza/.local/share/virtualenvs/store-api-wAMLFNlP/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/reza/.local/share/virtualenvs/store-api-wAMLFNlP/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/home/reza/.local/share/virtualenvs/store-api-wAMLFNlP/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 394, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/home/reza/.local/share/virtualenvs/store-api-wAMLFNlP/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/reza/.local/share/virtualenvs/store-api-wAMLFNlP/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/reza/.local/share/virtualenvs/store-api-wAMLFNlP/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/reza/.local/share/virtualenvs/store-api-wAMLFNlP/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 269, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/reza/.local/share/virtualenvs/store-api-wAMLFNlP/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/home/reza/.local/share/virtualenvs/store-api-wAMLFNlP/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 57, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/reza/.local/share/virtualenvs/store-api-wAMLFNlP/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 143, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class("_meta", Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/home/reza/.local/share/virtualenvs/store-api-wAMLFNlP/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 371, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/home/reza/.local/share/virtualenvs/store-api-wAMLFNlP/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 243, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length()
  File "/home/reza/.local/share/virtualenvs/store-api-wAMLFNlP/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 15, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._connections[self._alias], item)
  File "/home/reza/.local/share/virtualenvs/store-api-wAMLFNlP/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 62, in __getitem__
    conn = self.create_connection(alias)
  File "/home/reza/.local/share/virtualenvs/store-api-wAMLFNlP/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 193, in create_connection
    backend = load_backend(db["ENGINE"])
  File "/home/reza/.local/share/virtualenvs/store-api-wAMLFNlP/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 113, in load_backend
    return import_module("%s.base" % backend_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home/reza/.local/share/virtualenvs/store-api-wAMLFNlP/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 17, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

I'm sure installed 'mysqlclient' successfully and this is `Pipfile.lock` file :

```
{
    "_meta": {
        "hash": {
            "sha256": "fe52abfe897fbfb2bf81adbfa85d0678bc42ddce6bcd83f3e37e0a921d34273a"
        },
        "pipfile-spec": 6,
        "requires": {
            "python_version": "3.10"
        },
        "sources": [
            {
                "name": "pypi",
                "url": "https://pypi.org/simple",
                "verify_ssl": true
            }
        ]
    },
    "default": {
        "asgiref": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:89b2ef2247e3b562a16eef663bc0e2e703ec6468e2fa8a5cd61cd449786d4f6e",
                "sha256:9e0ce3aa93a819ba5b45120216b23878cf6e8525eb3848653452b4192b92afed"
            ],
            "markers": "python_version >= '3.7'",
            "version": "==3.7.2"
        },
        "django": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:7e4225ec065e0f354ccf7349a22d209de09cc1c074832be9eb84c51c1799c432",
                "sha256:860ae6a138a238fc4f22c99b52f3ead982bb4b1aad8c0122bcd8c8a3a02e409d"
            ],
            "index": "pypi",
            "markers": "python_version >= '3.8'",
            "version": "==4.2.4"
        },
        "mysqlclient": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:004fe1d30d2c2ff8072f8ea513bcec235fd9b896f70dad369461d0ad7e570e98",
                "sha256:04368445f9c487d8abb7a878e3d23e923e6072c04a6c320f9e0dc8a82efba14e",
                "sha256:530ece9995a36cadb6211b9787f0c9e05cdab6702549bdb4236af5e9b535ed6a",
                "sha256:5670679ff1be1cc3fef0fa81bf39f0cd70605ba121141050f02743eb878ac114",
                "sha256:68837b6bb23170acffb43ae411e47533a560b6360c06dac39aa55700972c93b2",
                "sha256:955dba905a7443ce4788c63fdb9f8d688316260cf60b20ff51ac3b1c77616ede",
                "sha256:9c6b142836c7dba4f723bf9c93cc46b6e5081d65b2af807f400dda9eb85a16d0"
            ],
            "index": "pypi",
            "markers": "python_version >= '3.8'",
            "version": "==2.2.0"
        },
        "sqlparse": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:5430a4fe2ac7d0f93e66f1efc6e1338a41884b7ddf2a350cedd20ccc4d9d28f3",
                "sha256:d446183e84b8349fa3061f0fe7f06ca94ba65b426946ffebe6e3e8295332420c"
            ],
            "markers": "python_version >= '3.5'",
            "version": "==0.4.4"
        },
        "typing-extensions": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:440d5dd3af93b060174bf433bccd69b0babc3b15b1a8dca43789fd7f61514b36",
                "sha256:b75ddc264f0ba5615db7ba217daeb99701ad295353c45f9e95963337ceeeffb2"
            ],
            "markers": "python_version < '3.11'",
            "version": "==4.7.1"
        }
    },
    "develop": {}
}
```

If I change the

```
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
```

back to

```
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqllite',
```

the error goes away.

Comment: Check how to correctly define the database settings for mysql, for example here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189813/setting-django-up-to-use-mysql#19189930

Answer (score 0):

You are pointing the mysql database to the sqlite file, hence the `ImproperlyConfigured` error.  The error message being displayed is misleading, and is probably a minor bug, assuming there is a way to distinguish between `mysqlclient` being installed and an improper configuration.

You need to define the following for a mysql database:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': DB_NAME,
        'USER': DB_USERNAME,
        'PASSWORD': DB_PASSWORD,
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Comment: It is the same erorr. Acturally ENGINE line is the line that generates the error